# A strange solution for a limit

Tags: limits

I have found this example ($s(n)$ is the digit sum):

[image]

For every positive $k$, I can see with GeoGebra that
$$
f(x)=\frac{\lfloor\log_{10} x\rfloor}{(\ln\ln x)^k}
$$
tends to zero so it is a lower bound but not useful as it does not diverge. How can one understand the given solution??

Comment: How did you find that it tends to zero? How large is the $n$ that you checked?

Comment: You find this obvious?  Really?  For $n=100$,$k=1$ we get $\frac {s(100!)}{\ln(\ln(100))}\approx 424$.  If you take $n=1000$ you get about $5453$.  What computation did you do?

Comment: That said, the official solution seems a bit glib.  How do you get from divisibility to a lower bound on the digit sum?  $52579\,|\,1000000001$ but the digit sum of the right hand is only $2$ while the $\log_{10}$ of the left hand is over $4$.  I believe it's known that the digits of $n!$ are uniformly distributed (at least approximately) if you ignore the large block of $0's$ that end the number.  But I don't see a cheap way to get a solid lower bound.

Comment: Please do not use pictures to convey mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for the reasons this should be avoided](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by getting an intuition of what happens by using equivalents:
$s(x) = O(\log(x))$, because at best $x$ is of the shape $10^k-1$ and in that case $s(x)=9k$.

By using Stirling's Formula, $\log(n!)$ is equivalent to $n\log(n)$.

Meanwhile, that denominator progress so slowly once you get to big $n$ values that it is pretty easy to be convinced that it will end up smaller than any arithmetic progression.

The presented solution isn't easy to follow, but it is intended to work as an illustration about how to use the lemma 16.3 previously presented in the book:

> Any multiple of $99...99$ (k 9s) has sum of its digits at least $9k$.

This means that if $10^{\inf(\log(n))}-1$ divides $n!$, then $s(n!)$ is at least $9*\inf(\log(n))$.
$9\inf(log_{10}(n))$ is equivalent to $\ln(n)$ (you can bound it between two sequences both equivalent to $\ln(n)$)

Meanwhile, this denominator is growing very slowly, and becomes way smaller than $log(n)$. Many people would find this obvious, but to prove it cleanly you can use L'Hôpital:

$L_k = \lim \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(\ln(n))^k} = \lim \frac{(\ln(n))'}{(\ln(\ln(n))^k)'} = \lim \frac{1/n}{\frac{k(\ln(\ln(n))^{k-1})}{n\ln(n)}} = \lim \frac{\ln(n)}{k(\ln(\ln(n))^{k-1})} = L_{k-1}/k$

This lets you do a nice induction over k: $L_0 = \lim \ln(n) = \infty$ and for any $k$, $L_{k+1} = L_k/(k+1) = \infty$.

Comment: Since you are interested in proving that the limit is $\infty$ you would need to bound $s(x)$ **from below**. $s(x) = 9k$ is a upper bound for the numbers of $k$ digits.

Comment: @jjagmath I know that, but still it proves that OP's hypothesis (that it converges to 0) is wrong.

Comment: @Lonaldin do you have the reference?

Comment: @AnneAunyme ,,Problems from the Book" by Andreescu. It is only the example. My hypothesis was btw that $
f(x)=\frac{\lfloor\log_{10} x\rfloor}{(\ln\ln x)^k}
$ goes to $0$ and therefore cannot be useful.

Comment: @Lonaldin
I can't easily find a copy of this book, but from the critics I read (https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/problems-from-the-book-by-titu-andreescu-and-gabriel-dospinescu-pp-554-6995-2008-isbn-9780979926907-xyz-press/CE76A6A884EBA437BD2160C7A40BBFCE), this is not just a collection of random unrelated problems. Usually an examples comes after something, what is it in your case?

Comment: @AnneAunyme Page 364: http://www.hexagon.edu.vn/images/resources/upload/48f705559d5da29b51bb76fc555d8c3c/problems-from-the-book-1-pdf_1380724174.pdf

Comment: @Lonaldin that's what I thought, see edit

Comment: Okay but now we have the lower bound $\frac{9\cdot \lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor}{(\ln\ln n)^k}$, which goes to $0$ for large $n$ and positive $k$.

Comment: @Lonaldin it doesn't. I added a demo for that.

Comment: Thanks, it seems as it goes to zero on geogebra but for very large numbers it goes up again. Thanks for your patience with me.